# How to update specific property in whole database in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to update a property in whole database.
Example I want to update property `name` if `name=='Gaurav'` then I want to replace this as `name='gsb'` in all documents in all collections, whether it is nested objects property. Is there any way to do this without knowing the structure of document, cause in each collection documents are of different structure. I want this query for Node JS.

What I tried is as follows. I am stuck in between.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var config = require('../config.js');
var async = require('async');
_ = require ('lodash');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + config.db_url + '/' + config.db_name, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collInfos) {
    async.each(collInfos,function(collectionDetails,cb){
        db.collection(collectionDetails.name,function(err, collection){
            if(err){
                    console.log(err)
            }
            else
            {
            collection.find().toArray(function(error, result) {
                            if(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                            else {
                                    _depthFirstSearch = (collection, input) => {
                                       let type = typeof collection;
                                       if (type === 'string' || type === 'number' || type === 'boolean') {
                                         return _.includes(collection.toString().toLowerCase(), input.toString().toLowerCase());
                                       }
                                       return _.some(collection, (item) => this._depthFirstSearch(item, input));
                                     }
                                    var data= _.filter(result, (item) => {
                                         return _depthFirstSearch(item, "Gaurav");
                                       });

                                    console.log(data)                                   

                            }
            });
        }
    })
    cb();
})
});
});
```

Comment: @chridam I found the all the records in database but not able to replace them. I will update my question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after lots of brainstorm. I wrote below function to achieve this.

```
var replaceAllInsatnceInDB=function(db_url/*localhost:27017*/,db_name,propName,stringToSearch,stringToReplace){
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + db_url + '/' + db_name, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
      db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collInfos) {
         async.each(collInfos,function(collectionDetails,cb){
            db.collection(collectionDetails.name,function(err, collection){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            else
            {   
                collection.find().toArray(function(error, result) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    else {
                        result.forEach(function(document){
                        var op=function(record){
                        if(record!== null && record!==undefined ){
                            var props=Object.keys(record);
                            var forObject=function(obj){
                                if(Array.isArray(obj)){
                                var forArray=function(arr){
                                    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                                        if(typeof arr[j] ==="string"){
                                            if(arr[j]===stringToSearch  && props[i]==propName){
                                                arr[j]=stringToReplace
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(typeof arr[j] ==="object"){
                                                                    forObject(arr[j]);
                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                            return(arr)
                                                        }
                                                        obj=forArray(obj)
                                                    }else{
                                                        op(obj);
                                                    }
                                                    return(obj);
                                                }
                                            for(var i=0;i<props.length;i++){
                                                if(typeof record[props[i]] ==="string"){
                                                        if(record[props[i]]===stringToSearch  && props[i]==propName){
                                                            record[props[i]]=stringToReplace
                                                            console.log()
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    if(typeof record[props[i]] ==="object"){
                                                        record[props[i]]=forObject(record[props[i]])
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        }
                                            return(record);
                                        }
                                        document=op(document);
                                        collection.update({_id : document._id},document,function(error,doc){
                                            if(error){
                                console.log(error)
                            }else{
                                console.log("template updated");
                            }
                                        })
                                    })


                            }

            });


        }
    })
    cb();
})
});
});
}
```